# visual studio making both static library and dll from same project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, object, build-process

I have a project that is being build as a DLL file.  is it possible to generate a static lib from the object files left over from compiling it as a dll using the lib.exe command as a post build step?  is there a way to tell lib.exe to create a static lib using all the object files found in a specific area without spefifying object files individually?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could try it.  Have you tried it by using a /LIST according to the LIB.EXE command line help?  Should be easy enough to write a batch script that looks for .obj files and then calls lib.exe with the appropriate parameters if it actually works no?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio uses a few different preprocessor definitions for DLLs and LIBs. This may work on some cases, but in the general case, it's not a good idea.

The standard way of doing things is to create a static library project to your liking.

If you really insist, you can call another instance of devenv.exe to build it. This can be done via a post build step.

Open a VS shell via the supplied batch file and execute.

```
devenv SOLUTION_NAME /Build /project PROJECT_NAME  /projectconfig CONFIG_NAME
```

Example:

```
devenv ConsoleApplication.sln /build /project ConsoleApplication /projectconfig Debug|Win32
```